# How to properly set up network interface

Tags: networking

I installed OpenMediaVault on my Raspberry Pi and connected a USB 3.0 LAN adapter to the Raspberry where a LAN cable is connected. I can access the hard drive, which is also connected to the Raspberry, and OMV remotely, so the LAN adapter works.

I have defined the following network interface (eth0 is the build-in lan and eth1 is the lan adapter).

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# eth0 network interface
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet6 manual
    pre-down ip -6 addr flush dev $IFACE
# eth1 network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.0.114
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

ifconfig Output:

```
[...]
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:68:ce:15  
          inet addr:192.168.0.114  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2743 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2559 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:283457 (276.8 KiB)  TX bytes:5385381 (5.1 MiB)
[...]
```

route output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

My problem is that I can't access websites outside my own network. For example the command

```
ping -c 4 google.com
```

returns

```
ping: unknown host google.com
```

So the command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

does not work either.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're probably missing nameservers ... `cat /etc/resolv.conf` ...  There are numerous methods of assigning namesevers.  I'm unfamiliar with OMV's default networking behavior.  However, from the [image file](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openmediavault/files/Raspberry%20Pi%20images/) it looks like they may be using network manager.

Comment: After installing OMV and playing around a bit, it looks like the network configuration is manageable through the web interface which should be available at the unit's IP address in your favorite browser. `ping raspberrypi.local` should respond with the unit's IPv4 address. The underlying default networking is performed via Network Manager... there's a command line interface `nmcli` and [here's how to setup a static address using nmcli](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290938/assigning-static-ip-address-using-nmcli)

Comment: From where do you ping? From the DHCP subnet behind eth0, or from subnet 192.168.0.0/24 behind eth1? Can you ping 8.8.8.8?

Comment: Yes I can ping 8.8.8.8. When I type ping -I eth1 google.com, I get the same error. I defined the eth1 interface in OVM's web interface, but the problem still persists. nmcli is not installed and I cannot install it, because I don't have access outside my own network. One thing to mention: When I plug the lan cable in the build-in box, I can access the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way, was not to make the interface static. Just used DHCP, with the disadvantage that the IP-Adress might change when restarting the Raspberry.